# I need to export the SVN log history in to a xml file in windows

Tags: svn

I tried exporting the SVN History log in Ubuntu machine using the following command and it worked fine. I used Rabbit SVN.

```
svn log -v --xml SVNPATH > /home/admin/Desktop/XXX.xml
```

I need to do the same in the windows machine also and am using tortoise SVN. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: The command-line svn.exe is still the same so the command will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this with TortoiseSVN.

You can automate Tortoise to get the logdialog or other stuff ([for details look here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)), but you cannot export the log into XML.

You need the commandline to do this(which you do not need to install, you can use a portable).

Comment: BTW there is an option within TortoiseSVN installer to install command-line tool.

Comment: You do not need to thank, but voteup or mark an answer is appreciated, as this is showing other people what was helping you.